# Navigation bar has wrong position when modal a view controller with flip horizontal transition in iOS 7

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uinavigationbar

When I am trying to modal a view controller with flip horizontal transition in iOS7, the origin of navigation bar is (0, 0) at beginning and then jump to the right position at (0, 20). Is it possible to make it behave the same with in iOS6? You can download the project [here](https://github.com/voicecho/NavigationBarPositionTest).

I have created a customized navigation bar as following:

```
@implementation MyCustomNavigationBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Custom-Nav-Bar-BG.png"];


    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,  0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

    if (IOSVersion <7) {
    }else{
        self.translucent = NO;
        self.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
        self.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    }
}

@end
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: hi,Did u solve the issue which is mentioned above?

Comment: can u plz tell me how to solve the filp transition in iOS 7?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I have the same problem with you. I think It's a bug with UIKit on iOS 7.

I added a little of code at viewWillAppear method on presentation

```
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

When I dismiss this view, I added:

```
-(IBAction)btnDonePressed:(id)sender {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
                      duration:0.75
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                    animations:nil
                    completion:nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This worked for me. Hope this helps you.

Comment: This also works for a segue that is presenting a modal `UINavigationController` via a flip animation. I added the `UIView` transition above with `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight` option to prepareForSegue and it fixed the rest of my issues with this bug. I will be submitting a radar for this w/ a sample project.

Comment: Perfect. Should be noted though, the first fix (on viewWillAppear) is for preventing the bump on the displayed modal view, the second fix is for preventing the bump when returning to original view.

Comment: On the second fix, for returning to the original view, you may need to test for device orientation to avoid conflicting animations. E.g. ````if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))...````

Comment: this fix works well for 4" devices, but still get a bump on return when 3.5" device.

Comment: can u explain how to use if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) in original view

Comment: this sort of works. it reduces the effect but it's still there though subtle.

Comment: Can anyone verify that the default flip animation duration is actually 0.75? Seems like it also be 1.0 or a number of values in that range. Thanks!

Comment: I have to modal views in the app I'm working on; both are dismissed with the flip animation. However, only one of them does the annoying navbar jump. In other words, I think it has to do with how the view is setup, and not a bug in iOS 7. So, a "native" fix should be possible.

Comment: I am transitioning from a `UINaviagtionController` (navigation bar hidden; hosts my login view) to a `UITabBarController` that has a `UINavigationController` (navigation bar showing - this is my app's main screen) on the selected tab, and was experiencing this issue. Removing the animations solved it, but Why are there any animations attached to the navigation bar  in the first place? I would like to have a cleaner solution than having to add that code to the `-viewWillAppear:` method of the top view controllers for ALL my tabs!

Comment: @NicolasMiari, it seems Apple fixed this issues. I don't have the problem on iOS 9. About your question, I guessed Apple attached some animations to change presenting view's frame after detecting. For more information about navigation bar on iOS 7, you can read this http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/61507315630/wrestling-with-status-bars-and-navigation-bars-on. I don't have a cleaner solution, this answer is only my solution. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hacking `[navigationBar.layer removeAllAnimations];`, something like this should work as well:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window duration:FlipDuration options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{
    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
        [self presentViewController:modalController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: Solved the issue, imho a better answer than the accepted one

Answer (score 3):

Just give the -20 in the xib in option "ios 6/7 Deltas"

or read this

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH66-SW1

Comment: I have tried to set the "ios 6/7 Deltas" of the navigation bar, but without help. Have you tried too?

Comment: These answers gave me some point, and I have worked around it, but failed to solve the problem.

Comment: I see your demo but its working fine here is values:-

 self.frame.size.height :44.000000
 version==7
 rect.size.height :44.000000
 self.frame.size.height :44.000000
 Test[430:a0b] version==7
 rect.size.height :44.000000

Comment: the frame value is correct, but the transition is weird, much different with in iOS6.

Comment: Can you leave me your email? Then I can send your the record video of the transition.