# iOS 7 Navigation Bar Jump on Flip Horizontal Segue

Tags: ios, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, visual-glitch

In my app when I transition both to and from navigation controllers with nav bars in iOS 7, the bars jump about 20px at the end of the animation. I know that this is a bug that has been discussed here before, but the solution offered up:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Only works for me in the segue to the new view controller, but not the other direction despite me adding that line to both view controllers.

Does anyone else have a workaround for this?

Comment: Where has it been discussed before?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19265558/5171) to a similar question includes a second fix that solves the problem for the reverse transition:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view
                  duration:0.75
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:nil
                completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```